# Вопрос про плагин datapicker

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Есть такой код:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker, #datepicker2" ).datepicker();
    $("#datepicker, #datepicker2").datepicker( "setDate" , "0");
});
```

И дата отображается в инпуте в таком формате: `01.01.2014`.
А нужно, чтоб отображалось название месяца, то есть `01 октября 2014`.

Подскажите, что прописать, а то я плохо разбираюсь в документации, не могу найти.  
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker().datepicker(
    'option', {
        'minDate': 0,
        'onSelect':function(e){
            var dateOptions = {year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric" };
            var date = new Date(e).toLocaleDateString('ru',dateOptions);
            $( "#datepicker" ).val(date);
            //alert(date);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Не помогло.

Comment: @websterjoy, работает http://jsfiddle.net/bemulima/z92fxwxm/2/

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dayNamesShort

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dayNames", [ "Dimanche", "Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi", "Samedi" ] );
```

Comment: вставил такую строку... ничего не изменилось вообще..
подскажите пожалуйста полный код, чтоб я просто мог заменить в файлике у себя, я в этом действительно плохо разбираюсь

Comment: ".selector" поменяли на свой селектор? Я незнаю, что там у вас #datepicker?

Comment: Конечно. Не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Формат даты  поменяй, там в инструкции написано.